# Case expression error when subquery returns more than one error

Tags: subquery, case

Hi have a `subquery` in CASE expression where it returns more than one row and it gives error saying **`subquery returns more than one row`** but my `subquery` will always return more than `1` more and need to fetch all the rows returned by the query.

Can you please help me to tune the query?

```
SELECT TS.ts_test_id "TEST ID",
    TS.ts_name "TEST NAME",
    TS.ts_responsible "Designer",
    DS.ds_step_order "Step Order",
    DS.ds_step_name "Step Name",
    TS.TS_USER_02 "Application", 
    CASE
        WHEN DS.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS.ds_description
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN DS_LN.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS_LN.ds_description
                ELSE
                  **(SELECT ds_description from DESSTEPS where ds_test_id = DS_LN.ds_link_test)**
            END
    END "Step Description",
    CASE
        WHEN DS.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS.ds_expected
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN DS_LN.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS_LN.ds_expected
                ELSE
                  **(SELECT ds_expected from DESSTEPS where ds_test_id =DS_LN.ds_link_test)**
            END
    END "Expected Result"
FROM dessteps DS
    LEFT JOIN dessteps DS_LN ON DS_LN.ds_test_id = DS.ds_link_test
    JOIN test TS ON DS.ds_test_id = TS.ts_test_id
        AND TS.TS_USER_02 = 'ABINRIM' --CHANGE THE APP NAME
ORDER BY DS.ds_step_order
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the output you're trying to create? Also, what database / SQL version are you using?

Comment: I actually Im executin this query on the quality centre database which is mainly oracle. The Select query higlighted with the stars returns two or more rows. The funcationality is There are are two tables Test and DESSTPES. For each TEST table there could be multiple rows in DESTEPS TABLE and there could be a link to TEST table. This Link is something when a Test has a design steps which in turn calls another design steps and that design steps might inturn call another steps.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I don't understand what you're doing well enough to give you a 100% answer, but the subquery in the select won't work; the select statement will only accept single values, not rows. I think you've also got your table aliases in the case statement muddled - I've had a go at fixing them below.

[A little piece of semantics: I'm going to call a self-join, i.e. when you join table to itself a "recursive step").

Do you have a variable number of recursive steps, or do you know how many times you have to self-join with DESTEPS? Either way you might find an elegant solution with a recursive query - I'm not familiar with Oracle, so I can't help you there, but e.g. [this link might help you](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

Alternatively, if you know the number of recursive steps, you can just self-join that many times. E.g.

```
SELECT TS.ts_test_id "TEST ID",
TS.ts_name "TEST NAME",
TS.ts_responsible "Designer",
DS.ds_step_order "Step Order",
DS.ds_step_name "Step Name",
TS.TS_USER_02 "Application", 
CASE
    WHEN DS_LN.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS.ds_description
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN ds2.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS_LN.ds_description
            ELSE
              ds2.ds_description
        END
END "Step Description",
CASE
    WHEN DS_LN.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS.ds_expected
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN ds2.ds_link_test is NULL THEN DS_LN.ds_expected
            ELSE
              ds2.ds_expected
        END
END "Expected Result"
FROM dessteps DS
    LEFT JOIN dessteps DS_LN ON DS_LN.ds_test_id = DS.ds_link_test
    JOIN test TS ON DS.ds_test_id = TS.ts_test_id
    LEFT JOIN dessteps ds2 ON ds2.ds_test_id = DS_LN.ds_link_test

    AND TS.TS_USER_02 = 'ABINRIM' --CHANGE THE APP NAME
ORDER BY DS.ds_step_order
```

Comment: This query actually doesn't work as it fetched all the records without replacing the recursive steps.

Comment: That's the thing - you haven't said what output you want, preferably with a few sample rows. The above query produces an output - a row per step. Do you want only one row per step? Then you need to write a query to aggregate your steps and join to that...